# Grid of four equally sized images - can't get them top aligned

Tags: html, css, frontend

I must be missing something obvious, but I'm trying to make a grid of four equally sized images and for some reason the two on the right aren't top aligning with the two on the left. They're about 10px lower. I really want to address this using inline CSS and I feel like I'm missing something.

```
<p>
   <a href="https://www.google.com/page1" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
     <img style="display: block; float: left; width: 49%; margin-top:5px;margin-right: 2%;margin-bottom:5px;" src="image1.jpg" alt="IMAGE 1" />
   </a>
   <a href="https://www.google.com/page2" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
     <img style="display: block; text-align: right; width: 49%; margin-right: 2%;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" src="image2.jpg" alt="IMAGE 2" />
   </a>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/page1" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <img style="display: block; float: left; width: 49%; margin-top:5px;margin-right: 2%;margin-bottom:5px;" src="image1.jpg" alt="IMAGE 1" />
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/page2" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <img style="display: block; text-align: right; width: 49%; margin-right: 2%;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" src="image2.jpg" alt="IMAGE 2" />
  </a>
</p>
```

Do I have an extra/missing tag somewhere? Is there an easier way to do this via inline CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
div{
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,150px);
  grid-template-rows: 150px;
  gap: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/page1" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="IMAGE 1" />
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/page2" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="IMAGE 1" />
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/page1" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="IMAGE 1" />
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/page2" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="IMAGE 1" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` on the `p` tags, *parent elements*, css. No need for those floats. Display flex will force the child content of the parent flex container to line up in row when in default mode.

[Basic concepts of Flex ~ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<p>
   <a href="https://www.google.com/page1" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
     <img style="display: block; margin-top:5px;margin-right: 2%;margin-bottom:5px;" src="image1.jpg" alt="IMAGE 1" />
   </a>
   <a href="https://www.google.com/page2" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
     <img style="display: block; text-align: right; margin-right: 2%;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" src="image2.jpg" alt="IMAGE 2" />
   </a>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/page1" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <img style="display: block; margin-top:5px;margin-right: 2%;margin-bottom:5px;" src="image1.jpg" alt="IMAGE 1" />
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/page2" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <img style="display: block; text-align: right; margin-right: 2%;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" src="image2.jpg" alt="IMAGE 2" />
  </a>
</p>
```

```
<p class='row'>

/* CSS */ 
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```